# How to Find EKS Fargate Cluster DNS name?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops, containerd

How to find the Cluster DNS name in EKS Fargate *https://DA21235B122C8728D6CB5E1E05320597.gr7.eu-west-1.eks.amazonaws.com*

Answer (score 0):

The DNS name of an EKS Fargate cluster can be found in the "Clusters" section of the Amazon EKS console.

Comment: I want to find it in a Kubernetes Api. How can I achieve that?

Comment: The kubernetes API is available at:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/api/